# First steps with threading failed

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Hi: please further down find my code.
I compiled using mingw with parameters -Wmain;-pedantic;-std=c++11;-Wall.
Codelite set the semicola between the compiler options

Here I tried to learn how to use thread and mutex: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex

The **main module** contains the global variable **std::mutex mtx** after the include section
The thread functions are declared and joined in the **main()** function; the function definitions for **friend class SL** can be found here as well. Class and method definitions are spread over the next two modules.

These are the error messages, which I cannot handle:
**Message 1**

```
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/thread:240:2: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int, int, SL&), int, int, SL> >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int, int, SL&), int, int, SL> >::_Indices)'
  operator()()
  ^~~~~~~~
```

**Message 2**

```
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/thread:233:29: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(std::__tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<void (*)(int, int, SL&), int, int, SL> >, std::__tuple_element_t<1, std::tuple<void (*)(int, int, SL&), int, int, SL> >, std::__tuple_element_t<2, std::tuple<void (*)(int, int, SL&), int, int, SL> >, std::__tuple_element_t<3, std::tuple<void (*)(int, int, SL&), int, int, SL> >)'
    -> decltype(std::__invoke(_S_declval<_Ind>()...))
     __invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~~~~
```

**Message 2* seems to make reference to some type of move constructor ...

I had the idea that the friend function is cause of the dilemma, but was not able to verify

Please help with this.

**main module**

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include "sl.h"
std::mutex mtx;

void play(int die1, int die2, SL& p){
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  mtx.lock();
  if (p.dice.size() > 0) {
    p.dice.resize(0);
    }
  p.set_dice(die1, die2);
  rollDice(p);
  mtx.unlock();
  }

void rollDice(SL& p) {
  int iFound = -1;
  int iAdd = p.dice[0] + p.dice[1];
  p.addPosition(iAdd);
  p.bounceBack();
  if (p.position == 100) {
    printResult(p, iFound);
    std::cout << "Game over" << std::endl;
    return;
    }
  if ((iFound = p.check(SL::ladders, p.position)) != -1) {
      p.setPosition(SL::ladders[iFound].second);
      iFound += 100;
      }
  else if ((iFound = p.check(SL::snakes, p.position)) != -1) {
      p.setPosition(SL::snakes[iFound].second);
      }// snakes, position + iAdd
  printResult(p, iFound);
  if (p.dice[0] == p.dice[1]) {
    mtx.unlock();
    play(rand() %6 + 1, rand() % 6 + 1, p);
    }
  }

void printResult(SL& p, int iFound) {
  std::cout << ++p.iTimes << ") "
            << p.get_name() << "<<<< "
            << p.dice[0] << "|"
            << p.dice[1] << " position: "
            << p.position;

  if (iFound != -1) {
    if (iFound > 100) { // this is a ladder field
      iFound -= 100;
      std::cout << " LADDER from "
                << SL::ladders[iFound].first << "|"
                << SL::ladders[iFound].second;
        }
    else {
      std::cout << " SNAKE from "
                << SL::snakes[iFound].first  << "|"
                << SL::snakes[iFound].second;
        }
      }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    }

int main()
  {
  srand(time(NULL));
  SL one("Player 1"),
                two("Player 2");
  std::thread t1 (play, rand() %6 + 1, rand() %6 + 1, one);
  std::thread t2 (play, rand() %6 + 1, rand() %6 + 1, two);
  while((one.get_position() != 100) && (two.get_position() != 100)) {
    t1.join();

    t2.join();
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

// Class Declaration

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

class SL {
  public:
  SL(const std::string& strName) : player(strName), position(0), iTimes(0) {}
  ~SL() = default;

  private:
    friend void play(int die1, int die2, SL& p);
    friend void rollDice(SL&);
    friend void printResult(SL&, int);
    static const std::pair<int, int> snakes[];
    static const std::pair<int, int> ladders[];
    std::string player;
    int position;
    int iTimes;
    std::vector<int> dice;
  protected:
    int check(const std::pair<int, int> field[], const int iField);
  public:
    void addPosition(const int iPosition);
    void setPosition(const int iPosition);
    void bounceBack();
    void set_dice(int die1, int die2);
    const int get_position() const;
    const std::string& get_name() const;
    const std::vector<int> get_dice() const;
    };
// friend function
void play(int die1, int die2, SL& p);
void rollDice(SL&);
void printResult(SL&, int =-1);
```

// Class methods - static variables

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include "sl.h"

inline void SL::addPosition(const int iPosition) {
  position += iPosition;
  }
inline void SL::setPosition(const int iPosition) {
  position = iPosition;
  }
inline void SL::bounceBack() {
  if (position > 100) {
    int iBounceBack = position - 100;
    position -= iBounceBack;
    }
  }
inline void SL::set_dice(int die1, int die2){
  if (dice.size() > 0) {
    dice.erase(dice.begin(), dice.end());
    }
  dice.push_back(die1);
  dice.push_back(die2);
  }
const int SL::get_position() const {return position;}
const std::string& SL::get_name() const {return player;}
const std::vector<int> SL::get_dice() const {return dice;}

int SL::check(const std::pair<int, int> field[], const int iField) {
  const int end = 10;
  int result = -1;
  for ( size_t idx = 0; idx < end; idx++) {
    if (field[idx].first == iField){
      result = idx;
      break;
      }
    else if (iField > field[idx].first)
      break;
    }
  return result;
}

const std::pair<int, int> SL::ladders[] {
      std::make_pair( 2, 38),
      std::make_pair( 7, 14),
      std::make_pair( 8, 31),
      std::make_pair(15, 26),
      std::make_pair(28, 84),
      std::make_pair(36, 44),
      std::make_pair(51, 67),
      std::make_pair(71, 91),
      std::make_pair(78, 98),
      std::make_pair(87, 94)
      };

const std::pair<int, int> SL::snakes[] {
      std::make_pair(16,  6),
      std::make_pair(46, 25),
      std::make_pair(49, 11),
      std::make_pair(62, 19),
      std::make_pair(64, 60),
      std::make_pair(74, 53),
      std::make_pair(89, 68),
      std::make_pair(92, 88),
      std::make_pair(95, 75),
      std::make_pair(99, 80)
      };
```

Comment: There is a bit of code, but this is just in case anybody wants to compile this and possibly see the error messages . All the threading items can be found either in main and play, function, which are in the main module. Thank you.

Comment: `std::thread` will, by default, pass parameters by value whereas your `play` function accepts its third parameter by reference -- `SL &`.  Try `std::thread t1 (play, rand() %6 + 1, rand() %6 + 1, std::ref(one));` and likewise for the other thread.  There's a dupe for this somewhere.  Can't find it right now.

Comment: Hi G.M. I tried to do that. My main() now looks like this: ```int main()
  {
  srand(time(NULL));
  SL one("Player 1"),
     two("Player 2");
  int die1 = rand() %6 + 1;
  int die2 = rand() %6 + 1;
  std::thread t1 (play, die1, die2, std::ref(one));
  std::thread t2 (play, die1, die2, std::ref(two));
  while((one.get_position() != 100) && (two.get_position() != 100)) {
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    }
  return 0;
  }
``` It still does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to go along with G.M.s suggestion and truly I was not able to make it.
For multi threading beginners this is a good stop:

https://hackernoon.com/learn-c-multi-threading-in-5-minutes-8b881c92941f

After reading through all of this I decided for the std::lock guard as so using the mutex mtx global variable from the main module:

```
void play(int die1, int die2, SL& p){
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
  if (p.dice.size() > 0) {
    p.dice.resize(0);
    }
  p.setDice(die1, die2);
  int iGameOver = 0;
  rollDice(p, iGameOver);
  if (iGameOver)
    return;
  }
```

In the rollDice function I used to have a recursive call to the rollDice function via play. This configuratin caused a dead lock and I got rid of that logic and replaced the recursion into two loops inside main.

```
int main()
  {
  srand(time(NULL));
  SL one("Player 1"),
     two("Player 2");
  while((one.getPosition() != 100) && (two.getPosition() != 100)) {
    int die1 = 0,
        die2 = 0;
    if (!two.gameOver()) {
      do {
        die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        play(die1, die2, one);
        }while(die1 == die2);
      std::cout << "-----------------" << std::endl;
      }
    if (!one.gameOver()) {
      do {
        die1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        die2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        play(die1, die2, two);
        }while(die1 == die2);
      std::cout << "-----------------" << std::endl;
      }
    }
  return 0;
  }
```

The respective logic making another call to rollDice() via play from rollDice was taken off the rollDice function, which now looks like this.

```
void rollDice(SL& p, int& gameOver) {
  int iFound = -1;
  int iAdd = p.getAdded();
  p.addPosition(iAdd);
  p.bounceBack();
  if (p.getPosition() == 100)
    p.setGameOver();
  if (p.gameOver()) {
    printResult(p, iFound);
    std::cout << "Game over" << std::endl;
    return;
    }
  if ((iFound = p.check(SL::ladders, p.getPosition())) != -1) {
      p.setPosition(SL::ladders[iFound].second);
      iFound += 100;
      }
  else if ((iFound = p.check(SL::snakes, p.getPosition())) != -1) {
      p.setPosition(SL::snakes[iFound].second);
      }// snakes, position + iAdd
  printResult(p, iFound);
  }
```

I am not really sure, where I went wrong with my original approach, but my first multi threaded test code is successfully implemented and without me posting and getting G.M.s suggestion, it just would not have taken place. Thank you.